# Django logging breaks the celery daemon

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm running django 1.3 with django-celery 2.4.2 on production.

Since I've activated django logging in the django settings.py file, the celery daemon (celeryd) wont run anymore.
Removing the logging function fixxes the issue.

My logging code in settings.py looks like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'write_to_log': {
            'level':'WARNING',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/path/to/project/logs/errors.log',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024*5, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter':'standard',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['write_to_log'],
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'propagate': True
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I added the following code before the LOGGING dictionary, which fixxes the issue.  If anyone has a more clean solution, I'd like to hear.

```
import sys
if not "celeryd" in sys.argv:
    LOGGING = ...
```

Comment: define "the celery daemon (celeryd) wont run anymore". What happens when you try to run it ?

Answer (score 2):

celeryd hijacks and configures the root logger, so there might be a conflict.

Try to disable the Celery log Hijack with:

```
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER=False
```